# DBIX class - Multiple result classes in same file

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I am using `DBIx::Class` for my MySQL database. I have many similar result classes created by subclassing from a parent schema using `Helper::Row::SubClass`. Is it possible to include more than one result classes in same .pm file? If yes, please suggest how.

Trying to use, for instance, `MyApp/Schema/Foo.pm` to define `MyApp::Schema::Foo` and `MyApp::Schema::Bar`, then using `$schema->resultset('Bar')` will produce an error like this:

```
DBIx::Class::Schema::source(): Can't find source for Bar at /path/to/MyApp.pm line 113
```

Comment: Why do you require multiple classes in one file?

Comment: For about 15-20 base classes I have to create about 30 subclasses of each class. Each subclass of a class differs only by 2 characters where I have to provide client id to subclass function.

Comment: So then each client has its own table in the database with its client id as part of the table name?  This sounds like something you'd want to generate using a template file and a loop or two.

Comment: Yes - @Len Jaffe, this is what I want. I was looking for a solution at run time based on client Id but having no way to do so I will now create static code for all tables. Please note I have to change table name as well as relationships when I create any result classes.

Comment: Other than to suggest that you can eval an entire package into existence at runtime, I can't help you further because you have not provided any examples (smaple code) what you're trying to do

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27862051/dbixclass-subclassing-result-class) for details of what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a result class in a file that doesn't match the class name, or a file with multiple result classes, you have to register the result classes manually using [register_class](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Schema#register_class). So in your Schema class, add:

```
__PACKAGE__->register_class(Foo => 'MyApp::Schema::Result::Foo');
__PACKAGE__->register_class(Bar => 'MyApp::Schema::Result::Bar');
```

Also make sure that the file containing the multiple resultset classes is outside of any directory searched by `load_namespcaes` or `load_classes`, and `use` the file manually.

Answer (score 0):

It's always possible to put multiple packages in the same file.

```
package MyApp::Schema::Result::Foo;

# Stuff

package MyApp::Schema::Result::Bar;

# Other Stuff

1;
```

It's rarely a good idea though.

Comment: I know this is possible according to Perl but I am not much aware of DBIx::Class internals and the result classes don't get uploaded unless the class name is same as filename. Error is "DBIx::Class::Schema::source(): Can't find source for <classname>"